# Generar Array con multiples objetos

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de generar un Array con estructura de objetos en su interior con la siguiente estructura:

```
var valores = [{ name: 'MongoDB', type: 'float', value: 25,{ name: 'MongoDB', type: 'float', value: 5 },{ name: 'MongoDB', type: 'float', value: 2 }];
```

A mi API Rest me llega la siguiente estructura:

```
{
  "subscriptionId" : "5a268a598dc68904bbc7b3cf",
  "originator" : "localhost",
  "contextResponses" : [
  {
    "contextElement" : {
      "type" : "Temperatura",
      "isPattern" : "false",
      "id" : "S_Temp001",
      "attributes" : [
        {
          "name" : "Tem_int",
          "type" : "float",
          "value" : 2,
          "metadatas" : [
            {
              "name" : "accuracy",
              "type" : "Float",
              "value": 2              }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name" : "Tem_out",
          "type" : "Integer",
          "value" : 1,
          "metadatas" : [
            {
              "name" : "Timestap",
              "type" : "Integer",
              "value": 33              }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "statusCode" : {
      "code" : "200",
      "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
    }
  }
  ]
  }
```

Tengo que tratar estos datos en mi **Back-end** para generar la estructura ya comentada anteriormente.

La forma en la que estoy intentando generar mi Array es de la siguiente forma:

```
    var params = req.body;
     var tmp2 = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < params.contextResponses.length; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes.length; j++) {
         for (var k = 0; k < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas.length; k++) {
           //console.log("nuevo log antes de petar: " + params["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value);

           tmp2.push('{' + //paramsheadersFiware_Service,
params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].name,
                    params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].type,
                    params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].value

                    + '}');
         }
       }
   }
   console.log("tmp2 --> ",tmp2);
```

**Recorriendo el estructura y luego haciendo un push al nuevo array.**

La respuesta que consigo es la siguiente:

```
[ '{Tem_int', 'float', '2}', '{Tem_out', 'Integer', '1}' ]
```

**Como se puede ver el formato no es el correcto, necesito las etiquetas antes de los valores he probado concatenando antes del Push pero no queda bien y las '' están mal puestas tendrían que ir dentro de {''} ¿Como puedo solucionar este problema?**

El objetivo es guardar múltiples documentos en MongoDB según el formato inicial que he comentado.

Sinceramente no se si existe alguna forma mejor de guardar en MongoDB, pero la idea es guardar mi Array de objetos y cada objeto sea un documento.

Comment: ¿Y por qué no lo guardas como lo recibes de la API, como un JSON?

Comment: Hola, la idea es guardar solo la información que necesito. por ejemplo esta no la necesito: "subscriptionId" : "5a268a598dc68904bbc7b3cf",
  "originator" : "localhost",

Comment: Generalmente las API tienen varios puntos de entrada o lo que es lo mismo, varias formas de filtrar los datos, lo óptimo sería obtener justamente una representación de los datos tal cual los necesitas, sin nada que sobre, e insertar esa respuesta en la BD. Si eso no es posible, entonces quizá sí le vería sentido a tu pregunta. Aunque todavía hay más datos que trae la respuesta y que serían desechados, como `metadatas`. Yo me refiero a que una API debe estar capacitada para traerte **justo lo que necesitas**, sin necesidad de desechar datos de la respuesta.

Comment: Buenas, en este caso esta respuesta viene de otra Api con esta estructura. La idea es parsear esta respuesta y añadir a cada colección la información que necesitemos, los metadatos irán en otra colección y se añadirán en otro Array. La idea es tener solo colección genérica con los valores de los datos y tenga dependencias con otras Por este motivo se quiere separar la respuesta.

Comment: Tú puedes extraer las partes que quieras del objeto, haciendo algo tan simple como esto: `const newJson = (({ contextResponses}) => ({ contextResponses }))(json);console.log(newJson);` En ese caso te devolverá un objeto solamente con lo que hay dentro de la clave `contextResponses`. Si quieres seguir  *limpiándolo*, para quitarle las claves `metadatas` por ejemplo, y la clave `statusCode`, también se podría hacer... aunque sigo pensando que la API debe tener formas de traer los datos limpios, no que el usuario de la misma tenga que ocuparse de *limpiarlos*  luego.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que, si quieres que tu array sea de objetos, debes crear los elementos como eso, *objetos*. Tú los estás añadiendo como `string`.

De este modo, en la parte de tu código donde agregas estos elementos, podrías intentar algo así:

```
   var obj = {
      name : params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].name, 
      type: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].type,
      value: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].value 
   };
   tmp2.push(obj);
```

> Por cierto, y sólo como sugerencia, cada vez que entres en un `for`,
>   podrías asignar el elemento a recorrer a una variable (local al ciclo)
>   con un nombre más corto, jejeje, para que no te quede tan saturado el
>   código ^^ (también puedes usar `foreach`, que te permite hacer lo
>   mismo).

Comment: ajajaj Muchas gracias solucionado. tendré que cambiar los nombre xk vaya tela lo largos que son....

Comment: yo incluso miraría el método [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)